# Im implementing react redux in my react project. but this error came dont know how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

> store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { bookReducers } from './reducers/bookReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  book: bookReducers,
})

const middleware = [thunk]
const initialState = {
  books: [],
  isLoading: false,
  eror: '',
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(...middleware)
)

export default store
```

> error I got in my console

[image]

**I got this error from provider component while adding prop store but its the same as in redux docs . what is happening here**

Comment: can you setup codesandbox with this issue?

Comment: I got blank screen in  my page.But when I remove that  <Provider store={store}> component it works fine.

Comment: still, could you provide a not working example on codesandbox?

Comment: I think you are confused between the `createStore` and `configureStore` of redux toolkit. `createStore` won't do the `applyMiddleware` for you while `configureStore` do. You can read more on `configureStore` [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) and the redux `createStore` with `applyMiddleware` example [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#using-middleware). To fix your problem, just wrap your middleware in the `applyMiddleware` like the example and I think you should be fine.

Comment: oh yes thanks brother it worked  now .God bless to both Damian Busz and tung pham.